# Generalized Pythagorean integer solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, recreational-mathematics

We know that $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ has infinitely integer solutions which can be written as 3-tuples for example (3,4,5).

Can we conjecture that $$x_{1}^n +x_{2}^n + \cdots +x_{n}^n = y^n$$ has infinitely many integer solutions for each $n \in \mathbb N$? If so how would one prove this to be correct?

I apologize if this is a simple question. I havent taken number theory but this is something that has caught my curiosity. Thanks in advance.

Comment: related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/62820/pythagorean-5-tuples

Comment: An answer to this would follow from solutions to [Waring's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring%27s_problem).

Comment: Waring's problem is about the worst case, e.g., the number of 6th powers necessary to express each number as a sum. That number will be greater than 6, so solving Waring won't tell you anything about writing a 6th power as a sum of 6 6th powers.

Comment: But, Red, you might want to insist on *positive* integer solutions, else you can have $x_1=y$, $x_2=\cdots=x_n=0$.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixth_power#Sums "no examples are yet known of a sixth power expressible as the sum of just six sixth powers."

Comment: Of course you can conjecture anything you want. But if the conjecture is to be taken seriously, you should provide some results that suggest that the conjecture might be true. Like, say, the result of a computer search for small $n$.